# Authlogic with nested attributes and polymorphic associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, authlogic

I'm having trouble with the following code:

```
User < AR
  acts_as_authentic

  belongs_to :owner, :polymorphic => true
end

Worker < AR
  has_one :user, :as => :owner
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
end

Employer < AR
  has_one :user, :as => :owner
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
end
```

I'd like to create registration forms based on user types, and to include authentication fields such as username and password. I currently do this:

```
UserRegistrationController < AC
  #i.e. a new Employer
  def new
    @employer = Employer.new
    @employer.build_user
  end
...
end
```

I then include User fields with `fields_for`. All views render fine, but here's the catch: I cannot build a User, it tells me `:password` is a wrong method, so I guess the authentication logic has been bypassed.
What should I do? Am I doing it wrong altogether? Should I drop polymorphic associations in favor of Single Table Inheritance? Whatever I do, I have to make sure it plays nicely with Authlogic.

Answer (score 1):

I'd approach the building of new users of either type in the opposite direction. ie:

```
#controller 
@employer = Employer.new
@user = @employer.build_user

#view
form_for @user |f|
  f.text_field :login
  f.password_field :password
  fields_for :owner, @employer |f_e|
    f_e.some_field :some_value

#controller
def create
  @owner = params[:owner][:some_employer_field_or_virtual_attribute] ? Employer.new params[:owner] : Worker.new params[:owner]
  @owner.save
  @user = User.new(params[:user].merge!(:owner => @owner)
  if @user.save
    ...
```

re. mentioned virtual attribute - if there's no field in the model, and thus in the form, which distinguishes user type as employer or worker then set an virtual attribute within each which you can put as a hidden boolean field in the form

Comment: Hey thanks! I'll try it out. What should I save in the create action? Should I save both separately?
I'd rather stick with with the has_one association, it seems more scalable. Besides, I'm not that worried about space right now.

Comment: I think you'll need to save both separately. Rails won't be able to determine which type of model is on the other end of the polymorphic relationship. Try | @employer = Employer.new(params[:employer]) | @employer.save | @user = User.new(params[:user].merge!(:owner => @employer)). You'll need to remove the accepts_nested_attributes_for from the model.

Comment: Hey, also in your original form definition, are you sure you weren't defining the user attributes in the owner fields? I'm going to post another answer because perhaps this should work. ^ See edit to original answer.

Comment: In the original form definition I have defined all user attributes. In that case, I get an error from activerecord stating that :password is not a valid method (it's true, it is not defined in the users table).

Comment: You should have a crypted_password and password_salt columns. If you have them try in script/console instantiating and saving a new user.

Comment: That's correct. I've always been able to create new users from console if I construct a user from the start. Could you provide me with an alternative code from the comment above? I have no way to know whether the :owner key in params hash is either a worker/employer.